# Using Linux eeprom (at24) driver from another driver

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

We have a 24xx `eeprom` on our custom board; it’s hooked into the device tree and we can read/write it from userspace. However I’m developing a driver to control misc `GPIO’s`, and I’d like it to also be able to read the `eeprom`. (The contents won’t be changing at all – it’ll be write-protected).

> I’m struggling to figure out whether/how the driver can hook into the
>   at24 driver somehow? (Perhaps `“if (chip.setup)
>   chip.setup(&at24->macc, chip.context)”`, but I can’t spot how to use
>   this)

Or what other ‘best’ methods there might be to get to the chip from the driver. (`Kernel` 4.4)

Comment: Are you trying to implement read protection via GPIO line?

Comment: There won't be any read protection. Write protection (WP pin) will be hard-wired.
The GPIO control in the driver isn't related to the EEPROM operation as such; I just wanted to implement the two parts in one driver. There'll be a single string stored in the EEPROM which I want to give the app simple access to (via the driver); also, the string may have an affect on the GPIO operations in the driver.

Comment: EEPROM contents is available via `sysfs`. Why do you need driver for that?

Comment: The driver isn't just to access the EEPROM - it does control of GPIO pins, but that control depends on the contents of the EEPROM. It just seemed that it would be 'neater' if it could do it through kernel-space access instead of doing (userspace) operations on sysfs. (Unless there's a kernel space route into the sysfs entry...?)

Comment: `at24` or any standard EEPROM driver provides  the access to the data via `sysfs`. It's done in NVMe (I suppose) framework. So, Looks like you driver can be easily done in user-space.